# Can I use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to perform replacement of properties on String at runtime?

Tags: spring, ehcache

In one area of our Spring configuration we are using:

**applicationContext.xml**:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
</bean>
```

However, ehcache.xml is not a standard spring bean configuration file but contains ${ehcache.providerURL} which we want to replace based on what we have configured with PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer elsewhere:

**ehcache.xml**:

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory
   ...
   providerURL=${ehcache.providerURL}
   ...
</cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory>
```

I could use the Maven/profile/filter combination, but that would create a build that is specific to the environment it is being built for.  What I really want to do, is to pre-process the ehcache.xml at runtime performing substitutions based the properties read by PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer and then pass the result of that into the EhCacheManagerBean.

At this point, I am thinking of somehow duplicating the functionality behind the @Value annotation since it can replace "bla bla bla ${property} bla bla bla" except I need to do this after reading a file from disk.

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Thanks.
-AP_

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some searching, here is the essence of what I came up with.  I packaged this into a Factory which accepts a resource and converts it after replacing all the lines with ${propertyPlaceHolder} with actual values of the holder.

```
    final ConfigurableListableBeanFactory
        factory =
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).getBeanFactory();

    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        try {
            final String
                result = factory.resolveEmbeddedValue(line);
            writer.println(result);
        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            log.error("Exception received while processing: " + line, e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

The benefit of this solution is that it is using the same facilities as Spring uses to resolve @Value("${fooBar}") annotations.  This means you can use SpEL and what ever else Spring would normally accept in the @Value annotation.  It is also integrated with PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

Hope this helps someone.

-AP_

Answer (score 7):

To manipulate strings directly, you could use the org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper

```
String template = "Key : ${key} value: ${value} "
PropertyPlaceholderHelper h = new PropertyPlaceholderHelper("${","}");
Properties p = new Properties(); 
p.setProperty("key","mykey");
p.setProperty("value","myvalue");
String out = h.replacePlaceholders(template,p);
```

It replaces values in a template with the corresponding property values.

Answer (score 1):

PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer works to replace properties within Spring configuration files. It does not replace properties in external files. Your problem can not be resolved with PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.

You can override `org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()` method and do whatever you want to do with xml before creating CacheManager.You know how clean it can be :)

Comment: There is some code in Spring that takes @Value("bla ${param} bla) and properly does the replacement.  I was thinking of somehow using this code at runtime to pass in the contents of my file as a string, and get back a string with parameters replaced.

Comment: After some digging I found this:

((ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext).getBeanFactory().resolveEmbeddedValue("${someValue}");

I can read any old file, then using this method resolve all placeholders.  Is there anything in Spring which will allow me to do this from the bean configuration without having to write more code?

Comment: I think Adi's answer is a pretty decent hack.  Read the XML into a string, do string substitution on the parts you want, set the string as the config location (InputStreamResource/StringBufferInputStream), then call super.

Comment: Adi, I would have definitely used your solution if I was not successful with a more general approach of being able to filter the any file for ${propertyPlaceHolders}. As it turns out, I found another case where we were configuring hibernate second level cache, so I needed to have a more general solution.